~も~も vs ~が~も nuance
I have encountered - in different contexts - most of the following sentences. I would say that they are all grammatically correct, so I suppose there are minor differences in nuance:

1a. この本もその本も好きです。
1b. この本とその本が好きです。
2. この本が好きですがその本も好きです。
3. この本も好きですがその本も好きです。

Note the presence of the conjunction が in the last two. I would say that 1a) and 1b) don't differ much, if anything the one with と is more neutral, isn't it?
Then 2) seems to consider the first book on its own and then the conjunction が expresses contrast because the speaker also likes that other book, which is supposedly different for some reason. The one that strikes me as the weirdest choice, as I would prefer 1a) to say the same thing. So what'a the difference between 2) and 3)? My guess is that the conjuction が is weaker for 3). Can you confirm (or not) my guesses?

Assuming the context is "Which book do you like?", the difference mainly lies in the exhaustive-listing function of が.

1a) The repeated も often carries a nuance of "this and that". It sounds like you like both books and find it difficult to choose one. "I like both of them!" or "I like this, and that (and many others)!"
1b) This uses an exhaustive-listing-ga, but you're singling out two books instead of just one. Among all books, you like these two (and not others). "It's this one and this one that I like."
2) An exhaustive-listing-ga is used to single out one specific book first, then you add "but I like this one as well". The emphasis is on the first book. "It's this one that I like, but I like this one, too."
3) This is similar to 1a). You like this one, but also that one (and possibly others). Perhaps you don't want to choose just one favorite. "(Yes) I like this, but I equally like this one."

1a) and 3) are similar, 3) tends to be used if you are asked like "You like this book, right?"
